# Hooking system (libc) functions on iOS at link time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

So I know it's possible on a jailbroken iOS device to inject a dylib into a running process and interpose/hook system functions. I'm wondering if it's possible on a non-jailbroken device to interpose system functions at either link or run time, assuming I'm the one building the app?  Maybe the equivalent on linux of using dlfcn and LD_PRELOAD?

An example: I want to take an app I've built that uses various Cocoa/Core Foundation abstractions for filesystem access and wrap the underlying open/read/write/close calls. I know about swizzling in Objective-C, but I'm looking for something at the libc level so I capture everything. This is for something test/debug related so it doesn't need to be App Store friendly. Thanks!

Comment: IIRC if you define a function with the same name as a that of a function in an external library, then the "local" name will shadow the one in the library (at link time).

Comment: did you get achieved hooking system functions?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible (to my knowledge) on non-jailbroken iOS device. All traditional forms of dynamic loading (interposing, dlopen/dlsym, etc.) have been removed.

Since you mention that your needs are related to test/debug, you might want to try to make use of DTrace if your problem exists on simulator. You can use DTrace on simulator, but not on real iOS device.